# Console won't work / state doesnt update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm working on my code. First of all my App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Flat from './components/flat.js'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      flats: []
    };
  }


componentDudMount() {
    const url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lewagon/flats-boilerplate/master/flats.json";
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
      this.setState({  //console.log(data);
        flats: data
      });
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
      <div className="main">
        <div className="search">
        </div>
        <div className="flats">
          {this.state.flats.map((flat) => {
            return <Flat flat={flat} />
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="map">
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Then my flat.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./flat.css";

class Flat extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const title = this.props.flat.price 
        + this.props.flat.priceCurrency + " - " + this.props.flat.name;

        const style = {
            backgroundImage: `url('${this.props.flat.imageUrl}')`
        };

        return (
            <div className="flat">
                <div className="flat-picture" style={style}></div>
                <div className="flat-title">
                {title}
                </div>
            </div>


        );
    }
}

export default Flat
```

First of all on line that should update state i wrote a console.log that should have give me a log in console. It doesnt, my console is blank. All i did was set up my react by create-react-app.

Second thing, my code doesnt fetch a json. I'm sitting on it for hours and can't see whats wrong. Thanks for help in advance.

Video that i'm following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ZTT9kw3PIE&t=3665s&index=4&list=PL3IsCNRIBp-jOC5vjf1ITYDVgwngDqtzz

Comment: You have a typo in this `componentDudMount`, it should be `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a type in lifecyle hook `componentDidMount`

Secondly, a console.log() statement is not valid inside an object, so

```
  this.setState({ //console.log(data);
    flats: data
  });
```

is invalid,

You can have a `console.log()` statement before `setState` like

```
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((data) => { 
  console.log(data);
  this.setState({  
    flats: data
  });
})
```

or use functional setState(although it isn't really useful here)

```
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((data) => { 
  this.setState(() => {
    console.log(data);
     return {flats: data}
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks guys. That's embarrassing that ive made such a stupid typo. You're right as well when it comes to console.log.

Comment: Glad it helped you out

Answer (score 1):

it need to be `componentDidMount()` not `componentDudMount()` , one more thing 
change your render methode to be like this , with this way you will only render when the state is updated

```
render() {
   if(!this.state.flats){
      return(<div>Loading ......</div>
      }
    return (
      <div className="app">
      <div className="main">
        <div className="search">
        </div>
        <div className="flats">
          {this.state.flats.map((flat) => {
            return <Flat flat={flat} />
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="map">
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```